# Unable to Register Chaincode & Successfully Start Blockchain Network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am following hyperledger fabric tutorial, and am having trouble registering my chaincode and possibly starting the docker image:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/

The following is the error I am getting when I try to register my chaincode:

```
$ ./Example
Hello world! starting [Ljava.lang.String;@5fd0d5ae
May 10, 2017 9:40:34 PM example.Example main
INFO: starting
May 10, 2017 9:40:34 PM io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$1 call
INFO: Created transport io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@7269e694(/127.0.0.1:7051) for /127.0.0.1:7051
May 10, 2017 9:40:36 PM io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$TransportListener transportShutdown
INFO: Transport io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@7269e694(/127.0.0.1:7051) for /127.0.0.1:7051 is being shutdown
May 10, 2017 9:40:36 PM io.grpc.internal.TransportSet$TransportListener transportTerminated
INFO: Transport io.grpc.netty.NettyClientTransport@7269e694(/127.0.0.1:7051) for /127.0.0.1:7051 is terminated
May 10, 2017 9:40:36 PM org.hyperledger.java.shim.ChaincodeBase$1 onError
SEVERE: Unable to connect to peer server: UNAVAILABLE
```

My blockchain network via docker is up and running, but the last log message is different than the expected log message (It says Connected to: [], which I assume is a null):

```
05:47:30.205 [peer] chatWithSomePeers -> DEBU 02f Starting up the first peer of a new network
05:47:30.205 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 030 Starting peer with ID=name:"vp0" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.3:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
05:47:30.206 [consensus/statetransfer] verifyAndRecoverBlockchain -> DEBU 031 Validating existing blockchain, highest validated block is 0, valid through 0
05:47:30.206 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 032 Validated blockchain to the genesis block
05:47:30.206 [consensus/handler] 1 -> DEBU 033 Starting up message thread for consenter
05:47:30.207 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 034 Starting Peer reconnect service (touch service), with period = 6s
05:47:30.207 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 035 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
05:47:36.209 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 036 Touch service indicates no dropped connections
05:47:36.209 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 037 Connected to: []
05:47:36.209 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 038 Discovery knows about: []
```

When I check for containers that are running docker shows me both of them are up, see below:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
7dec77752d52        hyperledger/fabric-peer         "sh -c 'sleep 5; peer"   20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:7050-7051->7050-7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   blockchain_vp0_1
ac91e9bc1b0e        hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc   "membersrvc"             24 hours ago        Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                                     blockchain_membersrvc_1
```

The following git command was used:
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric.git -b v0.6

I copied and pasted the exact values for the docker-compose.yml, see below:

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  ports:
    - "7050:7050"
    - "7051:7051"
    - "7053:7053"
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=false
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

Is there something I am missing here? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are working on Windows environment and did everything right except not defined any port forwarding into Oracle VM virtual box. you will have to configure 
Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager - > Setting - > Network -> Advance - > port forwarding -- and define as per attached image, run and enjoy.... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqsmx.jpg)

Happy Coding!